# Помоги исправить ошибку (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

```js
class Basket {
  constructor(order, price, count) {
    this.order = order;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
  }

  static totalPrice() {
    let total = this.price * this.count;
    console.log('Вы должны заплатить: ' + total + ' рублей');
  }
}

new Basket(1, 100, 5).totalPrice();
```

Вот ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Убрать `static` в объявлении метода.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Basket {
  constructor(order, price, count) {
    this.order = order;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
  }

totalPrice() {
    let total = this.price * this.count;
    console.log('Вы должны заплатить: ' + total + ' рублей');
  }
}

new Basket(1, 100, 5).totalPrice();
```

Собственно зачем вам там статик?

Comment: Просто у меня вот такое вот задание